# How can I remove the white border from Chart.js V2.6.0 pie chart?

Tags: jquery, json, twitter-bootstrap, chart.js, pie-chart

[image]

I am using Chart.js(V2.6.0) pie chart and I'd like to remove white lines between slices. Could someone tell me a way to do this?

I tried  segmentShowStroke: false but Not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

We can't totally remove the white line between the slice, but we reduce to by using borderWidth property. Here is a working link to [codepen](https://codepen.io/rjv4u/pen/brNXQa/)`"borderWidth":"0"` and reference to 
dataset properties available in [chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/doughnut.html)

Comment: I tried -
elements: {
        arc: {
            borderWidth: 0
        }
    }

and It worked for me, it totally removed the white line.

Answer (score 1):

The border can be removed using the following configuration options:

```
var options = {
  elements: {
    arc: {
      borderWidth: 0, // <-- Set this to zero
      borderColor:'#333'
    }
}
```

};

A full example in fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/vy7npk0j/2/